Simulating the Spread between Futures and Spot
I want to simulate the intra-day spread between an equity future and the spot index, but I'm struggling to find a method which would fit the required distribution. I've tested with ARIMA models but considering that the value will usually be equal to the cost of borrowing with some spikes, this model isn't a good fit and fails the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and Ljung-Box statistic.
Is there some way in which I could model the spot and then separately model the futures, adjusting correlation between the 2 based on volatility? I've also considered using a short rate model to estimate the rate across the period, but it hasn't yielded much success.

The spot price can first be modeled via a stochastic volatility process, for instance a Heston-like system:
$$ dS_t = \mu_t S_t\,dt + \sqrt{v_t} S_t\,dW_t^S, \quad dv_t = \kappa(\theta - v_t)\,dt + \sigma \sqrt{v_t}\,dW_t^v $$
where $W_t^S$ and $W_t^v$ are correlated Brownian motions. Concurrently, we introduce a short-rate model (to capture intraday funding changes), such as an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process:
$$ dr_t = \alpha(\bar{r} - r_t)\,dt + \beta\,dW_t^r $$
Then, we define the "ideal" futures price by integrating the short rate over the relevant period:
$$ F_t^{\text{ideal}} = S_t\,\exp\!\bigl(\int_t^T r_u\,du\bigr) $$
when dividends or convenience yields are negligible, or adjusting accordingly if they are not. However, to capture the empirical observation that the futures–spot spread is usually around the cost of carry but exhibits abrupt deviations, we introduce a jump-diffusion correction to the futures price itself:
$$ F_t = F_t^{\text{ideal}} + X_t $$
where $X_t$ follows a mean-reverting jump process such as an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck with compound Poisson jumps:
$$ dX_t = -\lambda X_t\,dt + \eta\,dW_t^X + J_t\,dN_t $$
The jump size $J_t$ can be drawn from a heavy-tailed distribution to account for large spikes, and $N_t$ is a Poisson process with an intensity parameter calibrated to the frequency of observed spread shocks. Correlation between $W_t^X$ and the Brownian motions driving $S_t$ and $r_t$ can be tuned to match observed co-movements, possibly allowing a state-dependent correlation that grows with volatility (for instance, by letting the correlation parameter be a function of $v_t$).
Here is sample code to illustrate this:
import numpy as np

def simulate_spot_and_futures(
    N=390,          # Number of intraday time steps (e.g., minutes in a trading day)
    S0=100.0,       # Initial spot price
    v0=0.04,        # Initial variance (Heston)
    r0=0.01,        # Initial short rate
    X0=0.0,         # Initial correction term for futures
    T=1.0,          # Total time in "days" (scaled so that 1.0 ~ one trading day)
    kappa=2.0,      # Mean reversion speed for variance
    theta=0.04,     # Long-term variance level
    sigma=0.5,      # Vol-of-vol
    alpha=3.0,      # Mean reversion speed for short rate
    r_bar=0.01,     # Long-term short rate
    beta=0.01,      # Volatility of the short rate
    lambda_ou=2.0,  # Mean reversion speed for X_t
    eta=0.005,      # Diffusion term for X_t
    jump_intensity=0.1,   # Poisson jump intensity for X_t
    jump_mean=0.0,        # Average jump size for X_t
    jump_std=0.02,        # Std dev of jump sizes for X_t
    corr_S_r=0.0,         # Correlation between spot and short rate
    corr_S_v=0.5,         # Correlation between spot and variance
    corr_r_v=0.0,         # Correlation between short rate and variance
    corr_S_X=0.3,         # Correlation between spot and X
    corr_r_X=0.0,         # Correlation between short rate and X
    corr_v_X=0.0          # Correlation between variance and X
):
    """
    Returns arrays S (spot), r (short rate), X (futures correction),
    and F (futures) over N steps from t=0 to t=T.
    """
    dt = T / N
    
    # Construct the correlation matrix for the Brownian increments
    # We have 4 correlated sources: dW^S, dW^v, dW^r, dW^X
    corr_matrix = np.array([
        [1.0,       corr_S_v,  corr_S_r,  corr_S_X],
        [corr_S_v,  1.0,       corr_r_v,  corr_v_X ],
        [corr_S_r,  corr_r_v,  1.0,       corr_r_X ],
        [corr_S_X,  corr_v_X,  corr_r_X,  1.0      ]
    ])
    
    # Ensure the correlation matrix is positive semi-definite
    L = np.linalg.cholesky(corr_matrix)
    
    # Initialize arrays
    S = np.zeros(N+1)
    v = np.zeros(N+1)
    r = np.zeros(N+1)
    X = np.zeros(N+1)
    F = np.zeros(N+1)
    cumulative_rate = np.zeros(N+1)  # For approximate integral of r_t
    
    # Set initial values
    S[0] = S0
    v[0] = v0
    r[0] = r0
    X[0] = X0
    
    for t in range(N):
        # Generate correlated normal increments
        dW = L @ np.random.normal(size=4) * np.sqrt(dt)
        
        dW_S, dW_v, dW_r, dW_X = dW[0], dW[1], dW[2], dW[3]
        
        # -- Heston-like spot/variance dynamics --
        v_plus = max(v[t], 0.0)
        S[t+1] = S[t] + S[t]*np.sqrt(v_plus)*dW_S
        v[t+1] = v[t] + kappa*(theta - v_plus)*dt + sigma*np.sqrt(v_plus)*dW_v
        
        # -- Short rate (Ornstein-Uhlenbeck) --
        r[t+1] = r[t] + alpha*(r_bar - r[t])*dt + beta*dW_r
        
        # -- Jump-Diffusion correction for futures (X_t) --
        jump = 0.0
        if np.random.rand() < jump_intensity * dt:
            jump = np.random.normal(jump_mean, jump_std)
        
        X[t+1] = X[t] - lambda_ou*X[t]*dt + eta*dW_X + jump
        
        # For numeric approximation to F_t^{ideal}
        cumulative_rate[t+1] = cumulative_rate[t] + r[t]*dt
    
    # Compute the futures price at each step
    for t in range(N+1):
        F[t] = S[t] * np.exp(cumulative_rate[t]) + X[t]
    
    return S, v, r, X, F


# Example usage:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    S_sim, v_sim, r_sim, X_sim, F_sim = simulate_spot_and_futures()
    print("Final Spot:", S_sim[-1])
    print("Final Futures:", F_sim[-1])
```​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​


I didn't consider using a poisson process to capture spikes, but this should help solve the volatility of the basis which an ARIMA model hasn't been able to do
